# Case of the mysteriously closed handle

Tags: haskell, conduit

First I will give you the code, then the error, then some type information. The questions are these: How can I figure out what is going on? How might I fix the problem?

```
readTask = do
   req' <-  parseUrl "https://10.64.251.32/rest/api/latest/issue/BNAP-291"
   manager <- newManager manSettings
   let req'' = applyBasicAuth (pack "sandboxer") (pack "sandboxer") req'
   Response _ _ _ body <-runResourceT $ http req'' manager 
   pBody <- runResourceT $
            body $$+- sinkParser json

   --   print pBody
   --   closeManager manager

   return ()
      where manSettings =
               def
                 { managerCheckCerts = \ _ _ -> return CertificateUsageAccept }
```

This compiles fine. Here's what happens when I run the compiled code

```
dist/build/Spike/Spike
Spike: <socket: 3>: hGetBuf: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

`body` is the following type

```
Data.Conduit.Internal.ResumableSource
(Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.ResourceT IO)
Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
```

Feedback appreciated, I don't know how to begin troubleshooting this.

Comment: Sounds like the other side closed the connection.

Comment: Shouldn't the `http req'' manager` and `body $$+- sinkparser json` calls be in one `runResourceT`? Something like this (providing it compiles): https://gist.github.com/f0e71c053e8b892c4c49

Comment: @Nathan - Give that man an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `runResourceT` call is closing the socket before the body is parsed. You will need to combine the two `runResourceT` calls into one. `ResourceT` is a `Monad` instance so you can use `do` notation and some minor surgery to free the socket after parsing is complete:

```
readTask = do
   req' <-  parseUrl "https://10.64.251.32/rest/api/latest/issue/BNAP-291"
   manager <- newManager manSettings
   let req'' = applyBasicAuth (pack "sandboxer") (pack "sandboxer") req'
   runResourceT $ do
      Response _ _ _ body <- http req'' manager 
      pBody <- body $$+- sinkParser json
      liftIO $ print pBody

   closeManager manager

   return ()
      where manSettings =
               def
                 { managerCheckCerts = \ _ _ -> return CertificateUsageAccept }
```